# Illuminate\Routing\Controller or App\Http\Controllers\Controller

Tags: php, laravel, class, controller, phpstorm

I'm new to PHP, using PhpStorm. I have a doubt, which is the difference between using

```
Illuminate\Routing\Controller
```

and

```
App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

I want to pass an API but whenever I have to decide which route for the Controller class import I doubt on the difference.

Can anyone explain me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Illuminate\Routing\Controller` is the controller class in the framework. `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` is the one in your project which extends framework's controller. If your controller has override methods or some base methods that you prefer them to be available to other extended controllers such as;

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\DateTime\DateTime;
use App\Traits\Partner\PartnerDetail;
use App\Traits\Redirect\RedirectRoute;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController; // this is in the framework
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    // Laravel Traits
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    // Project Traits
    use RedirectRoute, DateTime, PartnerDetail;

    public function someCommonMethod()
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->someCommonMethod();
    }
}
```

If you don't have anything special in your `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` then you may go with `Illuminate\Routing\Controller`